# Asynchronous redux thunk requires wrapoer function

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

My redux thunk requires a wrapper function. (My mockstore in jest does not need it)
Thunk is added as middleware in my store

Action that works:

```
export function getSettings (establishmentId: string) {
    return (dispatch: any) => {
        return () => {
            dispatch(settingsLoading())
            Client
                .getSettings(establishmentId)
                .then((settings: ISettings) => {
                    dispatch(getSettingsSuccess(settings))
                })
        }
    }
}
```

Dispatch:

`dispatch(getSettings(establishmentId))`

Action that does not work (but it does in my jest test):

```
export function getSettings (establishmentId: string) {
    console.log('GET SETTINGS')
    return (dispatch: any) => {
        dispatch(settingsLoading())
        return Client
            .getSettings(establishmentId)
            .then((settings: ISettings) => {
                // dispatch(getSettingsSuccess(settings))
            })
    }
}
```

When I do it without the wrapper function it tells me I should apply the thunk middleware (which I did)

```
return createStore(
        rootReducer,
        composeEnhancers(
            applyMiddleware(thunk)
        )
    )
```

Comment: Can you clarify "does not work"?  The second snippet you showed _should_ be correct.

Comment: It throws the error that I should intall thunk middleware for asynchronous actions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer, we made a mistake in our mapDispatchToProps and used a combination of bindActionCreators and just returning an object list:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any) => bindActionCreators(
    {
        getSettings: (establishmentId: string) => dispatch(getSettings(establishmentId))
    },
    dispatch
)
```

should have been:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any) => {
    getSettings: (establishmentId: string) => dispatch(getSettings(establishmentId))
}
```

Comment: This can be simplified down to just `const mapDispatch = {getSettings}`, using [the "object shorthand" form of `mapDispatch`](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-mapdispatchtoprops-as-an-object).